# Where to locate the unattend.xml schema

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, unattend-file

I'm in need of a way to modify an [unattend.xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722187(WS.10).aspx) file programmatically. It would be great if I could just serialize to and from an object. But to do so I would need to get a hold of the schema so that I can run it through XSD. The referenced link provides all the possible settings but it would be nice to have it in XSD format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate a XSD schema from an XML file using the [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.71).aspx) utility.

```
xsd.exe unattend.xml
```

Comment: Is there some way to ensure that the XML is complete and valid without the XSD? I'd rather generate the XML from the definition rather than the definition from the XML.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the unattend.xsd from installing the [Windows AIK.](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows+aik)